# Gravity of BitmapDrawable doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a `BitmapDrawable` in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:antialias="true"
        android:autoMirrored="true"
        android:dither="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:filter="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
/>
```

I used this bitmap for a Imageview like below:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/detail_img"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/colorAccent"
           android:src="@drawable/bitmap_drawable"/>
```

The result:
[image]
You can see there is some padding in top and bottom. And the bitmap didn't aligned to bottom of the imageview, but I set `android:gravity="bottom"` in the bitmap xml.
I also tried `android:gravity="top"`, It also didn't work. 
What's wrong with my code. I googled, but didn't find anything about it.

I just want to know why the `gravity` property in bitmap xml didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

---

I know I can set `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` to the imageview which can let the imageview alignd to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  android:adjustViewBounds.

Set this to true,  if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve.So, android:adjustViewBounds="true" which fixes the issue.

Comment: Im not sure but maybe , they want to prevent image go out from frame of screen

Answer (score 0):

Put your ImageView inside any LinearLayout and set linearlayout gravity to center or anyone you want Like Wise..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should be work..
Thank you

Comment: ImageView doesn't have a ``gravity`` property.